# Using long table to split a table across multiple pages

Tags: tables, longtable, texmaker, excel2latex

I am using the excel to latex add in to generate tables from excel, however, when the table is too long it is not split automatically between 2 (or more pages). Is there any easy way to do this? I have found the longtable package, however, I am not managing to use it with the following code produced by LateX

```
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Trial}
    \begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|r}
\cline{1-4}    Hello & How   & Are   & You   &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{1-4}    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{1}} & 2     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{4}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{5}} &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-2}    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & 3     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{1-4}    6     & 7     & 8     & 9     &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{1-4}    \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &  \bigstrut[t]\\
    \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &  \\
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

I am using a simple example to not get confused with the code here (this example does not span over 2 pages) but if it did, what changes are necessary?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've noted, in order to make LaTeX split a long table across pages, it's necessary to use a `longtable` environment instead of nested `table` and `tabular` environments.

The following example first shows the table produced by your code (with the code simplified here and there), followed by the same table produced using a `longtable` environment. The four key differences are:

- The `longtable` environment takes as its argument the material that would be specified as the argument of the `tabular` environment. Do *not* try to nest a `longtable` inside a `table`.
- Insert `\\` (line break directive) after `\caption`.
- Since the table's headers and footers may occur repeatedly, specify the repeated material explicitly. Header and footer material is delimited with instructions named `\endfirsthead`, `\endhead`, `\endfoot`, and `\endlastfoot`.
- No need to provide a `\centering` instruction; the `longtable` is centered by default.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,longtable,bigstrut,caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption{A Trial} \label{tab:addlabel}
\begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|}
\hline 
Hello & How & Are & You \bigstrut\\
\hline 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{1}} & 2 
& \multicolumn{1}{ c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{4}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{ c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{5}} \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-2} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & 3 & & \bigstrut\\
\hline 
6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \bigstrut\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{longtable}{|r|r|r|r|}
\caption{Another Trial} \label{tab:addanotherlabel}\\
   \hline 
   Hello & How & Are & You \bigstrut\\
   \hline
   \endhead  % delimiter for header
   \hline
   \endfoot  % delimiter for footer
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{1}} & 2 
& \multicolumn{1}{ c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{4}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{ c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{5}} \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-2} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & 3 & & \bigstrut\\
\hline 
6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \bigstrut \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: why this construct in the `longtable` example : `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{1}}` ? I tried it without nesting, i.e. `\multirow{2}[4]{*}{1}` and it works the same.

Comment: @Amar - Your assertion isn't correct: The OP's code, which I carried over to my answer, *centers* the material. Without the `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{...}` "wrapper", the material would be right-justified. (I did delete all  `\multicolumn{1}{r}{}` and `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}` directives. I also deleted the redundant fifth column and replaced `\cline{1-4}` with `\hline`.)

Comment: I have posted my approach, since It is not possible to put the entire MWE in comment.

Comment: @Amar - The two versions will give the same result in your example, but that's because you've changed the default column type from `r` to `c`, right? Anyway, I believe the OP's main concern is with what he/she needs to do to switch from a nested `\table`/`tabular` environment to a `longtable` environment. I suspect the particulars of the table material are probably of little practical relevance.

Comment: yep! I agree with your observations.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly modified `longtable`, `booktabs`, & `multirow` -based solution:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs} % To nicely typeset tabular material
\usepackage{longtable}  % For multipage tables!
\begin{document}
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{longtable}{ccccc}
\caption[Trial]{Trial\label{tab:addlabel}}\\
%
\toprule
Hello & How & Are & You \\
\midrule
\multirow{2}[4]{*}{1} & 2 & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{4} & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{5} \\
\cmidrule{2-2}
 & 3 &  &  \\
\midrule
6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: oops! my bad! I've removed them from the code now :) thanks @Mico !